# PsychoPy playing sounds with irregular delay in an EEG experiment

Tags: python, real-time, delay, eventtrigger, psychopy

I'm using PsychoPy to prepare an oddball paradigm in which I preset a picture on the screen for 7 seconds and during the picture presentation 14 consecutive sounds are displayed every half a second. For every sound onset I send a trigger to the parallel port. I then ran timing tests to see whether the sounds are played at the same time as the triggers.

While the triggers seem to be fine and arrive every half a second, this is not the case for the sounds. The sounds are played with a delay of 100ms-200ms after the trigger and the difference between consecutive sounds' onsets is not half a second. The size of the sound file doesn't make a difference and the delays seem to be the case both for very short sounds (10ms) and longer ones (250ms). I tried to add ISI at the very beginning of each trial and load both a picture and the sounds during that period but it didn't help.

I also tried to add the ISI before every sound and load the sounds during these shorts ISIs but it didn't help either. Do you have any idea how the problem could be solved? Is there any way ISI could help? Am I supposed to have one ISI at the beginning of the trial to load all the stimuli for that trial or multiple ISIs per trial, one per stimulus?

The delay for the visual stimulus (i.e. the picture) is small and constant across trials.

The code below plays only two sounds but demonstrates the issue well.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division
from psychopy import locale_setup, sound, gui, visual, core, data, event, logging, parallel
from psychopy.constants import (NOT_STARTED, STARTED, PLAYING, PAUSED,
                                STOPPED, FINISHED, PRESSED, RELEASED, FOREVER)

# Setup the Window
win = visual.Window(
    size=(1920, 1080), fullscr=True, screen=0,
    allowGUI=True, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[-1, -1, -1], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True)
snd_2_tr = 'sound1.wav'
snd_3_tr = 'sound2.wav'
picture_tr = 'pic.jpg'
win.setRecordFrameIntervals(True)
win._refreshThreshold = 1 / 60.0 + 0.004
image_tr = visual.ImageStim(
    win=win, name='image_tr',
    image='sin', mask=None,
    ori=0, pos=(0, 0), size=None,
    color=[1,1,1], colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1,
    flipHoriz=False, flipVert=False,
    texRes=128, interpolate=True, depth=0.0)
sound_2_tr = sound.Sound('A', secs=-1)
sound_2_tr.setVolume(1)
sound_3_tr = sound.Sound('A', secs=-1)
sound_3_tr.setVolume(1)
image_port_tr = parallel.ParallelPort(address='0xD010')
sound_2_port_tr = parallel.ParallelPort(address='0xD010')
sound_3_port_tr = parallel.ParallelPort(address='0xD010')
ISI_17 = core.StaticPeriod(win=win, screenHz=60, name='ISI_17')

# ------Prepare to start Routine "main_tr"-------
main_trClock = core.Clock()
t = 0
main_trClock.reset()  # clock
frameN = -1
continueRoutine = True
# keep track of which components have finished
main_trComponents = [image_tr, sound_2_tr, sound_3_tr, image_port_tr, sound_2_port_tr, sound_3_port_tr, ISI_17]
for thisComponent in main_trComponents:
    if hasattr(thisComponent, 'status'):
        thisComponent.status = NOT_STARTED

# -------Start Routine "main_tr"-------
while continueRoutine:
    # get current time
    t = main_trClock.getTime()
    frameN = frameN + 1  # number of completed frames (so 0 is the first frame)
    # update/draw components on each frame

    # *image_tr* updates
    if frameN >= 60 and image_tr.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        image_tr.tStart = t
        image_tr.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        image_tr.setAutoDraw(True)
    if image_tr.status == STARTED and frameN >= (image_tr.frameNStart + 420):
        image_tr.setAutoDraw(False)

    # start/stop sound_2_tr
    if frameN >= 90 and sound_2_tr.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        sound_2_tr.tStart = t
        sound_2_tr.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        sound_2_tr.play()  # start the sound (it finishes automatically)
    if sound_2_tr.status == STARTED and t >= (sound_2_tr.tStart + 0.25):
        sound_2_tr.stop()  # stop the sound (if longer than duration)
    # start/stop sound_3_tr
    if frameN >= 120 and sound_3_tr.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        sound_3_tr.tStart = t
        sound_3_tr.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        sound_3_tr.play()  # start the sound (it finishes automatically)
    if sound_3_tr.status == STARTED and t >= (sound_3_tr.tStart + 0.25):
        sound_3_tr.stop()  # stop the sound (if longer than duration)
    # *sound_1_port_tr* updates
    if frameN >= 60 and image_port_tr.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        image_port_tr.tStart = t
        image_port_tr.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        image_port_tr.status = STARTED
        win.callOnFlip(image_port_tr.setData, int(triggers_image_tr))
    if image_port_tr.status == STARTED and frameN >= (image_port_tr.frameNStart + 15):
        image_port_tr.status = STOPPED
        win.callOnFlip(image_port_tr.setData, int(0))
    # *sound_2_port_tr* updates
    if frameN >= 90 and sound_2_port_tr.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        sound_2_port_tr.tStart = t
        sound_2_port_tr.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        sound_2_port_tr.status = STARTED
        win.callOnFlip(sound_2_port_tr.setData, int(triggers_sound_2_tr))
    if sound_2_port_tr.status == STARTED and frameN >= (sound_2_port_tr.frameNStart + 15):
        sound_2_port_tr.status = STOPPED
        win.callOnFlip(sound_2_port_tr.setData, int(0))
    # *sound_3_port_tr* updates
    if frameN >= 120 and sound_3_port_tr.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        sound_3_port_tr.tStart = t
        sound_3_port_tr.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        sound_3_port_tr.status = STARTED
        win.callOnFlip(sound_3_port_tr.setData, int(triggers_sound_3_tr))
    if sound_3_port_tr.status == STARTED and frameN >= (sound_3_port_tr.frameNStart + 15):
        sound_3_port_tr.status = STOPPED
        win.callOnFlip(sound_3_port_tr.setData, int(0))
    # *ISI_17* period
    if frameN >= 0 and ISI_17.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        ISI_17.tStart = t
        ISI_17.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        ISI_17.start(60 * frameDur)
    elif ISI_17.status == STARTED:  # one frame should pass before updating params and completing
        # updating other components during *ISI_17*
        image_tr.setImage(picture_tr)
        sound_2_tr.setSound(snd_2_tr, secs=0.25)
        sound_3_tr.setSound(snd_3_tr, secs=0.25)
        # component updates done
        ISI_17.complete()  # finish the static period

    # check if all components have finished
    if not continueRoutine:  # a component has requested a forced-end of Routine
        break
    continueRoutine = False  # will revert to True if at least one component still running
    for thisComponent in main_trComponents:
        if hasattr(thisComponent, "status") and thisComponent.status != FINISHED:
            continueRoutine = True
            break  # at least one component has not yet finished

    # check for quit (the Esc key)
    if endExpNow or event.getKeys(keyList=["escape"]):
        core.quit()

    # refresh the screen
    if continueRoutine:  # don't flip if this routine is over or we'll get a blank screen
        win.flip()
```

Comment: You should post some code

Comment: This sort of question is probably more suited to be asked at the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org where there is opportunity for more back-and-forth discussion about your situation (SO is more suited to specific programming questions). e.g. this thread addresses some things potentially of relevance to you: https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/psychopy-2-sound-latency-an-update/4591